# Can I use 1/2" diameter screw in a 1 1/2" width wood board?

Tags: wood

I'm trying to hang a swing from under my deck. The joists of the deck have a 1 1/2" width. The screws I got to hang the swing are 1/2" in diameter. Will I have enough room on either side of the screw if I put it in the wood to hang safely?

Edit: The question seems to have changed as I now found a hanger with screws that are .31" in diameter. I'll link the type of swing for context. I'll also link the smaller hangers. SUPER DEAL 40 Inch Blue Saucer Tree Swing Set for Kids Adults 800lb Weight Capacity Waterproof Flying Swing Seat Textilene Fabric with Adjustable Hanging Ropes for Outdoor Playground, Backyard a.co/d/hzo712q SELEWARE Swivel Swing Hangers Stainless Steel Swing Hooks Heavy Duty Ceiling Swing Mount for Porch Swing Hammock Chair Heavy Bag Yoga Silk Tire Swing Set Indoor Swing Olympic Rings 2 Pack a.co/d/37YpkgF

Comment: It sounds like you are thinking of putting the screws into the end of the joists?  I perfer not to use the ends for something like that.  A drilled hole from side to side of a joist for a bolt would be better strength.

Comment: I don't know that I could get something to have the swing hang appropriately from the side of the joist.

Comment: Are you planning to screw into/through the sides of the joist, or screw into the *bottom* of the joist?  What are the fasteners at the top of the swing ropes (or whatever)?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how joist orientation works, but it's the side facing the ground and is the thinnest side of the board (1 1/2"). The swing has carabiners to connect to something. I did link the swing type and a smaller hook in another comment below.

Answer (score 6):

If all you're going to do is *hang* the swing, then you'd probably be fine.

If someone is actually going to sit in the swing, or heaven forbid, actually *swing* in it, then you're probably going to have the joist split and the swing fall. There is a *tremendous* amount of dynamic load in a moving swing, even if it's "just" a little kid on it.

You'd probably be a lot better off using a 4x6 cut to fit between two joists, attached with joist hanger brackets (using the proper size brackets for your size lumber and filling every hole with a proper joist hanger nail), then putting the screw into the 4x6.

Comment: Thanks for the response! If I get a smaller screw would that be sufficient?

Comment: @Erik unlikely, because then the hardware is probably not going to be strong enough to hold up the swing. Attach two 4x4 or 4x6 boards to at least two or maybe even three joists at a 90 degree angle to the joists, then hang your swing from the pair of new boards.

Comment: It would be useful to all if the DV explained why. I don't give two hoots about the points, but knowing what's wrong with this suggestion would be good for me and the OP.

Comment: @Erik changing the size of the hanger bolt could have other, undesired, consequences, like the bolt not being strong enough to support the swing. What is the minimum bolt size recommended by the manufacturer? I wouldn't go below that...

Comment: I can't find any recommendations for bolt size. I'll link the type of swing for context. I'll also link the smaller hangers.                   SUPER DEAL 40 Inch Blue Saucer Tree Swing Set for Kids Adults 800lb Weight Capacity Waterproof Flying Swing Seat Textilene Fabric with Adjustable Hanging Ropes for Outdoor Playground, Backyard https://a.co/d/hzo712q 
                            SELEWARE Swivel Swing Hangers Stainless Steel Swing Hooks Heavy Duty Ceiling Swing Mount for Porch Swing Hammock Chair Heavy Bag Yoga Silk Tire Swing Set Indoor Swing Olympic Rings 2 Pack https://a.co/d/37YpkgF

Comment: Add that info to your original question so everyone can find it. It's a bit lost down here in the comments.

Comment: It's added, thanks.

Comment: @Erik note those mounts are for *indoor* applications.  Based FreeMan's answer, and the design of the swing, I think you could use some eye bolts through his "blocking" piece.  Assuming you can find any that are long enough (and use large washers).